# how to send a name to different functions

Tags: c++

Hi i am a scrub but like c++ but i cant figure out how to send a name to a function. an example of what i mean is this
ps i have looked here for help befor but never asked for help. so it may not be sent correctly

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//here is where i would like to send the name
int use()
{
cout<<name<<endl;
return 0;
}

int main()
{
//this is the name i want to send
string name;
cout<<"please enter name"<<endl;
cin>>name;
use();
return 0;
}
```

and i dont want it to be a globle string i need it to send and receive the name as it will be passed around to be used.
your help is needed

Comment: [functions tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call use from main with the command `use(name)` but you also need to declare use with a string parameter since your passing it a string parameter so your use function should look like:

```
int use(string myString)
{
    cout<<myString<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Also i dont know if your returning 0 from this function for a reason but its not like main where you should return 0 at the end so if you dont need that you can do this instead:

```
void use(string myString)
{
    cout<<myString<<endl;
}
```

Comment: thanks so much it works great!!! and that code i sent was writen for the question i am trying to make a simple text based game atm. again thank you so much!

Comment: @Naithiz if you like my answer lease upvote/accept it

Comment: kk i think i did that

Comment: I believe you meant to replace 'name' (actual parameter) with 'myString' (formal parameter) in the cout statement of  function use(0)

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN nice catch thank you. Just edited my answer

Comment: @EdHeal Yes however i didnt really want to confuse him because he is clearly a beginner of beginners so i just did the simplest thing that could answer his question. He can worry about performance issues when he gets a little more experienced

Answer (score 0):

as you are using cpp, you can also use:

```
    void use(string &myString) {
        cout << myString << endl;
    }
```

Write in your main:

```
use(string_blabla);
```

This is a "reference". Your PC only sends the Adress of your string to the use function and so no data will have to be copied (which needs time). Ofc at this point this effect is not noticeable but I just wanted to show some of the advantages of c++.  :)

Joiny